# How does `alert` defined in a function in strict mode even though `this` is `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, html

I thought we can use `alert('foo')` instead of `window.alert('foo')` because in the browser context, `this = window` by default, so `alert('foo')` would automatically mean `this.alert('foo')` which would be equivalent to `window.alert('foo')`.

Therefore, I was not expecting the `alert` function to be defined in a function in strict mode because when strict mode is enabled, `this` is `undefined` in the function.

Here is the code that demonstrates my confusion.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('----- foo -----')
  console.log('this: ' + this);
  console.log('window: ' + window);
  console.log('alert: ' + alert)
  console.log('window.alert: ' + window.alert)
  console.log('this.alert: ' + this.alert)
}

function bar() {
  'use strict'
  console.log('----- bar -----')
  console.log('this: ' + this); // this is undefined
  console.log('window: ' + window);
  console.log('alert: ' + alert) // how is alert defined when this is undefined?
  console.log('window.alert: ' + window.alert)
  console.log('this.alert: ' + this.alert)
  console.log('----- end -----')
}

foo();
bar();
```

Here is the output.

```
"----- foo -----"
"this: [object Window]"
"window: [object Window]"
"alert: function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
"window.alert: function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
"this.alert: function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
"----- bar -----"
"this: undefined"
"window: [object Window]"
"alert: function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
"window.alert: function alert() {
    [native code]
}"
TypeError: this is undefined
```

Comment: Wait.. Isn't `this` in strict is `undefined`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, `this` is `undefined` for a function called in strict mdoe. What's your point?

Comment: `TypeError: this is undefined` - Expected behaviour, right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, it is expected behaviour. Once again, what is your point?

Comment: `alert` is a global function, so it is accessible. That's my point. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't quite understand. What has `alert` being a global variable got to do with `this` being `undefined` in strict mode?

Comment: Er... I got your question confused. Sorry, don't mind! `:)`

Comment: `this` is just an identifier which points to *something*. In the first case, it points to the `window` object, in the second, it points to `undefined`. That doesn't mean the `window`  object itself (which holds all global variables) disappears.

Comment: @squint: *"That doesn't mean the window object itself (which holds all global variables)..."* Well, it used to, until ES2015's `let`, `const`, and `class`. :-) Now we have two kinds of globals: Ones that become properties of the global object, and ones that don't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's interesting. I just got done reading that in your answer. Thanks for that tidbit! However, testing in both Chrome and Firefox, it seems to define a property on `window`. Perhaps I've misunderstood some part of it? https://jsfiddle.net/g1oprg3c/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah, thank you. Firefox is misbehaving but Chrome demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: @squint: Actually, it may be that they're always supposed to create non-property globals, but Chrome's loose mode doesn't handle it correctly yet. I'm looking at the spec trying to figure that out...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Cool, let me know if you would. I thought I remembered hearing that strict mode wasn't going to be altered, but of course that may have changed at some point.

Comment: @squint: I'm fairly sure `let`, `const`, and `class` are always supposed to create non-property globals. They [create entries in the current *LexicalEnvironment*](http://goo.gl/Twm0da), whereas `var` [creates entries in the current *VariableEnvironment*](http://goo.gl/9vCBkF). Most importantly, the section [handling global declaration instantiation](http://goo.gl/jwJmzB) clearly handles `var` and `function` differently from lexically-defined bindings and doesn't call *CreateGlobalVarBinding*. (Sorry, had to shorten those URLs; they're all to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. It'll be interesting to see how it all shakes out in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought we can use `alert('foo')` instead of `window.alert('foo')` because in the browser context, this = window by default

No, variable resolution (technically *identifier* resolution) has nothing to do with `this` in JavaScript. (You may be thinking of Java or C#, where instance members are accessible with or without `this.` from within instance methods. JavaScript's `this` is very different from  `this` in Java or C#.) The reason we can use `alert` or `window.alert` is that `alert` is a global variable.

Identifier resolution works like this: If the identifier isn't defined in the current scope, the JavaScript engine looks at the nearest enclosing scope, and then to the next nearest enclosing scope, etc. Global scope is the overall container, so globals are available everywhere (unless shadowed by a declaration in a given scope). E.g.:

```
// (In loose mode)
var foo = "bar";
function Ctor() {
    console.log("this is window? " + (this === window));     // false
    console.log(foo);                                        // "bar"

    function level2() {
        console.log("this is window? " + (this === window)); // true
        console.log(foo);                                    // "bar"
    }

    level2();
}
var c = new Ctor();
console.log("this is window? " + (this === window));         // true
console.log(foo);                                            // "bar"
```

Note how it doesn't matter what `this` is.

As for why `alert` is available both on its own (as a global) and also as a property of `window`: In browsers, `window` is a global variable referring to the global object (which is also available as `this` in loose mode at global scope). Until ES2015, all global variables are also properties of the global object, so `alert` is the global variable and `window.alert` is the equivalent property. (Not entirely relevant to your question, but for completeness: In ES2015, globals created via `var` or function declarations and such still are properties of the global object, but it also became possible to create globals that aren't properties of the global object [with `let`, `const`, and `class`]. But all the standard ones defined for the web environment remain old-style globals that are also properties.)